# How to pass a 2D array to an x86 assembly function in C

Tags: c, arrays, assembly

I'm trying to work on an assembly function that can work on a 2d array in c, but I'm having trouble just trying to pass it. I keep receiving "type" errors because the prototype function doesn't match the function called in main. I've tried many different types of declaration, but I can't get them to align.

So how do I pass a 2D array to an assembly function correctly?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern void start(int*,int,int);
void printfunction(int r,int d, int arr[][d]);

int main(void)
{
    int aRow = 5;
    int aDepth = 5;

    int array[5][5]={{1,2,3,4,5},{6,7,8,9,1},{2,3,4,5,6},{7,8,9,1,2},{3,4,5,6,7}};

    start(array,aRow,aDepth);

    printfunction(aRow,aDepth,array);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function prototype -

```
extern void start(int*,int,int);
```

You function `start` expects first parameter  to be of type `int *` (*as prototype declared*), but when you call it in `main` you pass argument of type `int [][]` -

```
start(array,aRow,aDepth);
      ^^^^array is a 2-d array of int.
```

Change type of first parameter to `int [5][5]`(*an example*) . And then pass `array` to your function.

Comment: I receive these errors when I try this ^^ : `main.c:4:1: error: array type has incomplete element type
 extern void start(int [][],int,int);
 ^
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:15:5: error: type of formal parameter 1 is incomplete
  start(array,aRow,aDepth);
  ^`

Comment: @Riker Ofcourse you need to specify the size of array . It was just a right type answer I mentioned. You will need to specify the size . Array without size is of incomplete type .

Comment: you're right I added a size in the 2nd index and it worked. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Riker Since it is an assembly function which doesn't care bout types, and considering how you are passing array size, it might be better to pass a void*, or address of *the first element of array* as int*

Comment: @hyde is the address of the first element in the array not passed using this method?

Comment: @Riker yes, but this method fixes one dimension of array, so you should remove that as parameter (assuming those two int parameters are array size, if they're not then never mind!).